# snowflake python connector utility function write_pandas is inserting incorrect values

Tags: pandas, snowflake-connector

I have encountered the following issue using `write_pandas`

I have table with the structure as below:

```py
create transient table abc(
    col1 number(32,16)
)
```

I am inserting data by creating the DataFrame as below:

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([(62009.7009562123700055),columns=['COL1'])
```

But in the table i see the data as

```
62009.7009562123763712
```

Which is weird. Any suggestions on why this happening with `write_pandas`?

Answer (score 0):

The data types such as FLOAT/DOUBLE/REAL (underlying using DOUBLE ), all are approximate values, they are all stored as DOUBLE which has a precision/scale of 15/9. When we are unloading floats/doubles, columns are unloaded to CSV or JSON files, Snowflake truncates the values to approximately (15,9). Precision is always not accurate. Snowflake can’t precisely represent any arbitrary value with double precision, it's as per industry standard.

Please refer to this Tech Note: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Floating-point-data-types-in-Snowflake

This is the reason the precision is not accurate after 15 digits.

Thanks,
Sujan